# Matplotlib Artist: Define position in data coordinates but size in display coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

To my surprise I found no question on Stack Overflow specifically tackling this question.

I want to add an artist, a circle, to my matplotlib plot. The circle shall be positioned using data coordinates and shall also move with the data, i.e. panning shall be enabled. But at the same time the size of the circle shall be fixed in display coordinates and the size shall not change with the zoom, i.e. the limits of the plot.

My first suggestion would be to use a proper transform, but as it seems the transform is applied on both, the position and the size of the artist object. So how can I seperate those two parameters from each other, so that I can accomplish the desired behaviour?

@gboffi's answer suggests using Matplotlib's ScaledTransformation in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms, patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = (0.2,), (0.5,)
ax.plot(xdata, ydata, "o")
ax.set_xlim((-0.05, 1.05)), ax.set_ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
ax.grid()

trans = (transforms.ScaledTranslation(xdata[0], ydata[0], ax.transData))

circle = patches.Circle((0, 0), 20, fill=None, transform=trans)
ax.add_patch(circle)
plt.show()
```

This actually works but requires to define the position of the circle in the transformation and set the actucal xy-coordinates of the circle to (0, 0). Since I want to change the position of the circle occasionally and already have a bunch of code for that, I'm looking for a transformation that achieves the same behaviour but allows me to specify the xy-coordinates in the actual artist object and not the transformation. Is that possible?

This question is not a duplicate of this question: [Matplotlib artists to stay the same size when zoomed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678950/matplotlib-artists-to-stay-the-same-size-when-zoomed-in) The linked question is only about zooming. The aspect of panning is neiter touched in the linked question nor in its accepted answer.

Comment: @tmdavison This question is different from the question referenced as original. The _original_ question is about zooming, this question is about panning, and the aspect of panning is not touched either in the _original_ question or in its accepted answer.

Comment: @gboffi you are right, thank you. reopened

Comment: Thanks for reopening. I deleted my new question and edited the new relevant parts to this question.

Comment: @gboffi I just wanted to mark your question as correct answer but now it's deleted. What happened?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that, as a consequence of your edit of Aug 4 _"I'm looking for a transformation that achieves the same behaviour but allows me to specify the xy-coordinates in the actual artist object and not the transformation"_,  it's not a solution to your actual question.